Sudden buzz and dead note on electric guitar - No settings changed
I have Samick LS 11L electric guitar. It’s a bit old, purchased sometime in 2004. I guess it seems to have lived its life. As far as Struss rod is concerned it’s fully tightened and no more turns left. Action is okay and saddle height is low. If I raise it, then action will become higher. Strings I have been using 9 – 42.
I am amateur and don’t play too much or use tremolo etc.
Just recently when I have not modified anything, just naturally 3-rd fret on 1-st E string has started to buzz and more specifically it seems it’s almost dead as if it quickly mutes itself after playing.
I do not hear same level of output thru speaker and after playing it, it quickly mutes itself.
I am clueless why it happened. Do you have any suggestions for fixing it, if at all any DIY fix is possible?
I am anyways going to restring it but before that if anything I can try?

If you currently live in a planet that has weather, that’s probably what happened. Neck geometry changes when the weather changes. You cannot set up a guitar and leave it for ever and never have to adjust it again. If that were possible, they’d set it up correctly at the factory and you wouldn’t need setup adjustments.

Your problem may be that your truss rod is TOO tight. A truss rod needs to be adjusted so that the neck relief is correct, not be as tight as possible. If it is too tight lower frets will buzz and the action may be too low to allow proper vibration of the strings. Check YouTube for videos on how to adjust the truss rod, John Carruthers has a very good one. Also, electric guitars do not generally wear out that much over time if they are maintained.

Thank you for your comments. What I mean by 'it has lived its life', is that gradually over the years, it has reached a point where further adjustments are difficult. If I will loosen the Truss Rod a bit then neck will warp. To counter that over the years I have been gradually tightening it and now no more turns are left.

There is supposed to be an ever so slight concave curve to a fingerboard in order for the instrument to play properly. If the neck relief is set correctly even with the truss rod completely tightened then a new E string and slightly higher action on that string may take care of the problem. If not you may have an excessively worn 4th or 5th fret.

When you made prior truss rod adjustments, did you make measurements of the relief?

I finally took it to a luthier. He kept it with him for 2 days and fixed the issue. He did not disclose what was the issue and what was the fix though.

If a single string suddenly has a problem, the first step is usually to change the strings. Strings can go bad, such as by uneven stretching,  developing a "kink" or bent/worn spot on a heavily played fret, or other deformations. The extra "wobble" or movement can cause buzzing and fretting problems.
A string change will easily rule out the strings as the problem when doing diagnosis.
At a single fret on a single string, I would examine the fret, and the fret behind it and look for either sinking of the problem fret, or raising of the fret behind it. A popped fret will have a little space where the fret meets the fingerboard. Frets sometimes pop at the edges, which can cause buzzing on a single string.
Your truss action should also be checked. Changes in humidity can cause enough swelling in the neck to cause problems on a guitar with nearly flat neck relief. If you push down on the first and 14th frets, you should see some space between the strings and the middle frets, about the thickness of a medium or heavy pick. If the strings touch frets all the way across, your truss is too tight, and can cause buzzing on some of the frets.
If you have never had a fret level done on the guitar, it is a recommended service.  Many guitars don't come from the factory with the frets leveled. A fret level job will make it so the guitar's action can be as low as the instrument will allow.

There are a couple of reasons I've come across. First is that the string itself has a kink in it at that fret. Could be that the guitar has fallen and landed on that spot, on something hard, which caused the damage. May be impossible to see easily. Solution: new string.
Second the fret wire has sunk/worn. That will allow the fretted 3rd to choke at the 4th fret, but will be a more unusual problem. Solution: most will take it to a luthier.

I’m curious what you mean by “kink”, because what I think of when I read that word is something that would be a very obvious problem and you would be able to see it and you’d know the string is messed up right away.

@ToddWilcox - not necessarily - I've seen it several times, or rather experienced it several times, where a string has a deformation after being banged against something hard.

@ToddWilcox - what may be a perfectly obvious problem to you or me, may well not be perceived as such by others, and vice versa for that matter. It may only be a small kink, but even that will affect the choking. Obvious first call is to replace string, as in my first solution. Worth a dv?
